# How to convert ADF Pipeline Run Id (string) to GUID?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a table in a SQL database with a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data type

[image]

I would like to populate this table with the Pipeline Run Id parameter in Azure Data Factory

[image]

When I pass this parameter, it is passed as a string value, my table in the SQL database expects a value GUID() value. Is there a way to convert the parameter to GUID() type. Or should I consider changing the datatype in the target table?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably be better served by changing the SQL data type to a varchar if that's possible. Pipelines don't have a variable type for guid. They also do not have a conversion function for string to guid. The [guid() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#guid) generates a new guid value but returns a string. The [Data Flow expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions) doesn't even contain a reference to guid. All in all, my conclusion is if you can just treat them as strings you should.

Comment: Data Flow is uuid(), btw: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#uuid

Comment: Thanks @MarkKromer, that's (unfortunate but) good to know. It also returns a string, so the point still holds true that there is no concept of a guid/uuid data type.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in guys. Unfortunately it seems that Joel is correct, changing the data type of the table is my best bet here. Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an older thread, it might benefit someone who stops by.
There is a way to achieve what you need by creating a stored procedure in DB that accepts as argument the pipeline run id as string (or nvarchar), and inserts into the table. Even if you keep your column datatype as uniqueidentifier, Azure SQL database is able to perform this type conversion seamlessly. I have tried it and it works.